# How Can i use @String xml in ad unit - admob App Open Ads

Tags: admob, ads

Here Sample Of My code

Strings.xml

`<string name="AppOpen_id">ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/3419835294</string>`

AppOpenManager.java

`private static final String AD_UNIT_ID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/3419835294";`

For Example I Need To Get App-pub from string something Like `@string/AppOpen_id`

How can I Do it !

AppOpenManager.java Full Code

```
/** Prefetches App Open Ads. */
public class AppOpenManager implements LifecycleObserver, Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks {
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "AppOpenManager";
    private static final String AD_UNIT_ID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/3419835294";
    private AppOpenAd appOpenAd = null;

    private AppOpenAd.AppOpenAdLoadCallback loadCallback;

    private final MyApplication myApplication;
    private Activity currentActivity;
    private static boolean isShowingAd = false;
    private long loadTime = 0;


    /** Constructor */
    public AppOpenManager(MyApplication myApplication) {
        this.myApplication = myApplication;
        this.myApplication.registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(this);
        ProcessLifecycleOwner.get().getLifecycle().addObserver(this);
    }


    /** LifecycleObserver methods */
    @OnLifecycleEvent(ON_START)

    public void onStart() {

        showAdIfAvailable();
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onStart");
    }


    public void showAdIfAvailable() {
        // Only show ad if there is not already an app open ad currently showing
        // and an ad is available.
        if (!isShowingAd && isAdAvailable()) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Will show ad.");

            FullScreenContentCallback fullScreenContentCallback =
                    new FullScreenContentCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onAdDismissedFullScreenContent() {
                            // Set the reference to null so isAdAvailable() returns false.
                            AppOpenManager.this.appOpenAd = null;
                            isShowingAd = false;
                            fetchAd();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent(AdError adError) {}

                        @Override
                        public void onAdShowedFullScreenContent() {
                            isShowingAd = true;
                        }
                    };

            appOpenAd.show(currentActivity, fullScreenContentCallback);

        } else {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Can not show ad.");
            fetchAd();
        }
    }


    /** Request an ad */
    public void fetchAd() {
        // Have unused ad, no need to fetch another.
        if (isAdAvailable()) {
            return;
        }
        loadCallback =
                new AppOpenAd.AppOpenAdLoadCallback() {
                    /**
                     * Called when an app open ad has loaded.
                     *
                     * @param ad the loaded app open ad.
                     */
                    @Override
                    public void onAdLoaded(AppOpenAd ad) {
                        AppOpenManager.this.appOpenAd = ad;
                        AppOpenManager.this.loadTime = (new Date()).getTime();
                    }

                    /**
                     * Called when an app open ad has failed to load.
                     *
                     * @param loadAdError the error.
                     */
                    @Override
                    public void onAdFailedToLoad(LoadAdError loadAdError) {
                        // Handle the error.
                    }

                };
        AdRequest request = getAdRequest();
        AppOpenAd.load(
                myApplication, AD_UNIT_ID, request,
                AppOpenAd.APP_OPEN_AD_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT, loadCallback);
    }

    /** Creates and returns ad request. */
    private AdRequest getAdRequest() {
        return new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    }


    /** Utility method to check if ad was loaded more than n hours ago. */
    private boolean wasLoadTimeLessThanNHoursAgo(long numHours) {
        long dateDifference = (new Date()).getTime() - this.loadTime;
        long numMilliSecondsPerHour = 3600000;
        return (dateDifference < (numMilliSecondsPerHour * numHours));
    }

    /** Utility method that checks if ad exists and can be shown. */
    public boolean isAdAvailable() {
        return appOpenAd != null && wasLoadTimeLessThanNHoursAgo(4);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@NonNull Activity activity, @Nullable Bundle bundle) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityStarted(@NonNull Activity activity) {
        currentActivity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResumed(@NonNull Activity activity) {
        currentActivity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityPaused(@NonNull Activity activity) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityStopped(@NonNull Activity activity) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivitySaveInstanceState(@NonNull Activity activity, @NonNull Bundle bundle) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityDestroyed(@NonNull Activity activity) {
        currentActivity = null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
lol))) 
public AppOpenManager(MyApplication myApplication) {
        this.myApplication = myApplication;

this.AD_UNIT_ID = myApplication.getString(R.string.AppOpen_id);
        this.myApplication.registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(this);
        ProcessLifecycleOwner.get().getLifecycle().addObserver(this);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a functional class

```
import static androidx.lifecycle.Lifecycle.Event.ON_START;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Application;
import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleObserver;
import androidx.lifecycle.OnLifecycleEvent;
import androidx.lifecycle.ProcessLifecycleOwner;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdError;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.FullScreenContentCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.appopen.AppOpenAd;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.LoadAdError;

/** Prefetches App Open Ads. */
public class AppOpenManager implements  LifecycleObserver, Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks{

    private static final String LOG_TAG = "AppOpenManager";
    private static String AD_UNIT_ID;
    private AppOpenAd appOpenAd = null;
    private static boolean isShowingAd = false;
    private Activity currentActivity;
    private long loadTime = 0;

    private AppOpenAd.AppOpenAdLoadCallback loadCallback;

    private final MyApplication myApplication;

    /** Constructor */
    public AppOpenManager(MyApplication myApplication) {
        this.myApplication = myApplication;
        this.myApplication.registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(this);
        ProcessLifecycleOwner.get().getLifecycle().addObserver(this);
        AD_UNIT_ID = myApplication.getString(R.string.AppOpen_id);
    }

    /** LifecycleObserver methods */
    @OnLifecycleEvent(ON_START)
    public void onStart() {
        fetchAd();
        //Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onStart");
    }

    /** Request an ad */
    public void fetchAd() {
        // Have unused ad, no need to fetch another.
        if (isShowingAd) {
            return;
        }
        loadCallback =
                new AppOpenAd.AppOpenAdLoadCallback() {

                    @Override
                    public void onAdLoaded(AppOpenAd ad) {
                        if (!isShowingAd ) {
                            AppOpenManager.this.appOpenAd = ad;
                            FullScreenContentCallback fullScreenContentCallback =
                                    new FullScreenContentCallback() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onAdDismissedFullScreenContent() {
                                            // Set the reference to null so isAdAvailable() returns false.
                                            AppOpenManager.this.appOpenAd = null;
                                            isShowingAd = false;
                                        }

                                        @Override
                                        public void onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent(AdError adError) {}

                                        @Override
                                        public void onAdShowedFullScreenContent() {
                                            isShowingAd = true;
                                        }
                                    };

                            appOpenAd.setFullScreenContentCallback(fullScreenContentCallback);
                            appOpenAd.show(currentActivity);
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAdFailedToLoad(LoadAdError loadAdError) {
                        // Handle the error.
                    }

                };
                AdRequest request = getAdRequest();
                AppOpenAd.load(
                    myApplication, AD_UNIT_ID, request,
                    AppOpenAd.APP_OPEN_AD_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT, loadCallback);
    }

    /** Creates and returns ad request. */
    private AdRequest getAdRequest() {
        return new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    }


    /** ActivityLifecycleCallback methods */
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Activity activity, Bundle savedInstanceState) {}

    @Override
    public void onActivityStarted(Activity activity) {
        currentActivity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResumed(Activity activity) {
        currentActivity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityStopped(Activity activity) {}

    @Override
    public void onActivityPaused(Activity activity) {}

    @Override
    public void onActivitySaveInstanceState(Activity activity, Bundle bundle) {}

    @Override
    public void onActivityDestroyed(Activity activity) {
        currentActivity = null;
    }
}
// gradle 

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation files('libs/commons-math3-3.6.1.jar')
    implementation 'androidx.viewpager2:viewpager2:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:19.8.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'

    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-process:2.3.1'


    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:20.0.0'

    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0"
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.3.1'
    //noinspection LifecycleAnnotationProcessorWithJava8
    annotationProcessor 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:2.3.1'

}
```

Comment: Please Clarify or add some more detail as to your query.